# Single-Line Text <br> Tag Bug

Tags: glass-mapper, text-field

I'm encountering a bug that injects break tags into my single-line text fields after saving. We are working in Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 and using GlassMapper to render fields. When I enter text into the component, everything looks fine:

[image]

When I delete the text in the input area using the backspace key, instead of [No text in field] displaying, I get empty whitespace:

[image]

I thought somehow there was still a break tag or whitespace character in the box, however checking the HTML there was nothing in the span tag for the input:

```
<span class="scWebEditInput scEnabledChrome" id="fld_1E94649685104A9AAC2CFB1EC424D8D1_A03773D2427E4231992E62F0A2EB97C0_en_1_943d2feea2f3494f969d854e31a32bc3_8019_edit" contenteditable="true" sc-part-of="field" scdefaulttext="[No text in field]" scfieldtype="single-line text" sc_parameters="prevent-line-break=true"></span>
```

Now, once I save the page with the empty box, break tags appear in the input:

[image]

Here is the code for the example component I've used but this is happening in other Single-Line Text fields as well:

```
@using Code.GlassMapper
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Code.ViewModels.GeneralText>

<div class="row margin-bottom-10 generalText">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @if(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor || !Model.Title.IsEmpty()){
            <h3>@Editable(x => x.Title)</h3>
        }
        @Editable(x => x.Text)

        @if (Model.Button != null || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing) {
            <p class="margin-left-0 margin-top-0">
                @Editable(x => x.Button, GlassHelpers.AddCssClassParameter("btn-u btn-u-small")) <span class="small">@(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing ? " (button)" : "")</span>
</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I've checked the Standard Values template and there is no break tag there. I'm unsure of where this tag is originating from and why it only appears to be an issue in IE/Safari. Has anyone experienced this issue before? Any ideas on where to go with this? Thanks for the help!

Edit:

I originally couldn't see this but when I hit 'Edit as HTML' on the span tag in the debugger I found a break tag in it. It appears as though the second the text is removed from the input, the break tag appears in the HTML instead of [No text in field].

```
<span class="scWebEditInput scEnabledChrome" id="fld_1E94649685104A9AAC2CFB1EC424D8D1_A03773D2427E4231992E62F0A2EB97C0_en_1_943d2feea2f3494f969d854e31a32bc3_8019_edit" contenteditable="true" sc-part-of="field" scdefaulttext="[No text in field]" scfieldtype="single-line text" sc_parameters="prevent-line-break=true"><br></span>
```

Comment: Hi, if you are using multi-line text field, there are 3 issues fixed from sitecore through support tickets in adding <br> ( html break tags)  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/748022
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/148401
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/812014   but not sure on single line text. You can take it to sitecore support team if its unresolved from your end.

Comment: can you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530035/line-breaks-in-sitecore-single-line-textbox